# How do I retrieve the username that a Windows service is running under?

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-services

Given a service name, I would like to retrieve the username that it runs under (i.e. the username shown in the 'Log On' tab of a service's properties window).

There doesn't appear to be anything in the `ServiceController` class to retrieve this basic information. Nothing else in `System.ServiceProcess` looks like it exposes this information either.

Is there a managed solution to this, or am I going to have to drop down into something lower-level?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using WMI, with the System.Management you can try the following code:

```
using System;
namespace WindowsServiceTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Management.SelectQuery sQuery = new System.Management.SelectQuery(string.Format("select name, startname from Win32_Service")); // where name = '{0}'", "MCShield.exe"));
            using (System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher mgmtSearcher  = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(sQuery))
            {
                foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject service in mgmtSearcher.Get())
                {
                    string servicelogondetails =
                        string.Format("Name: {0} ,  Logon : {1} ", service["Name"].ToString(), service["startname"]).ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(servicelogondetails);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

You can then later substitute the commented code with your service name, and it should only return the instances of your service process that is running.

Answer (score 6):

WMI is your friend. Look at [Win32_Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418%28VS.85%29.aspx), specifically the `StartName` property. You can access WMI from C# via the [System.Management.ManagementClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementclass.aspx).

If you've not used WMI before, [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/satisharveti/tocontrolservicesrunninginasystem05302006100035AM/tocontrolservicesrunninginasystem.aspx) article seems to be quite a good tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

You can find this using the Windows Registry, reading the following string value, replacing `[SERVICE_NAME]` with the name of the Windows Service:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\[SERVICE_NAME]\ObjectName
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
```

but the most obvious you will get LOCAL SYSTEM or NETWORK. The reason that you cannot show this user - that service can manage multiple users (shared by desktop, attached to current windows session, using shared resource ...)
System starts service, but any user can use it.

Comment: Then you can get the Name property of the WindowsIdentity object returned from the above command.

Comment: -1 This returns the `WindowsIdentity` of the current user, not of a specified service.

Comment: @Pwninstein as usual service is started from SYSTEM or NETWORK credentials - not from "logged in" users. See my edits about this. So clarify you want get system account that starts service (my answer is correct about this) or current logged-in user list, that could use this service?

Comment: *Usually* services run as Local System or Network Service, but you can install a service to run under a standard user account (which we do in the project I'm working on).

Comment: @Pwninstein - in this case you will get correct from GetCurrent()

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I'm trying to do: I would like to get the username a particular service is running under. I would like to do this from a completely separate client application (i.e. all of the code to retrieve the username is in the client). Your suggestion to user `GetCurrent()` will not work because, according to MSDN, it "Returns a WindowsIdentity object that represents the current Windows user." In this case it will be the WindowsIdentity of the current Windows user running the CLIENT application, not the WindowsIdentity of the SERVICE.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works fine for me:

```
    ManagementObject wmiService = new ManagementObject("Win32_Service.Name='" + this.ServiceName + "'");
    wmiService.Get();
    string user = wmiService["startname"].ToString();
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

```
    public String getUsername() {
    string username = null;
    try {
      ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\root\\cimv2");
      ms.Connect();
      ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery
              ("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
      ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
              new ManagementObjectSearcher(ms, query);
      foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get()) {
        username = mo["UserName"].ToString();
      }
      string[] usernameParts = username.Split('\\');
      username = usernameParts[usernameParts.Length - 1];
    } catch (Exception) {
      username = "SYSTEM";
    }
    return username;
  }
```