# How to get a Windows Service logon credentials

Tags: c#, windows-services

There are numerous examples of how to set the user logon credentials for a Windows Service however I can't discover how you first ascertain what the current credentials are set for that Windows Service.

What I want to do is:

```
If(WinService.logonCredentials == LocalUser)
   WinService.logonCredentials = new logonCredentials;
```

Is there a class that I can access that will give me the required data and/or possibly other settings for the Windows Service as well?

Answer (score 3):

Im not sure, but if you cant do it with classes built in .net probably only way is using WMI.

This is Win32Service class:

```
    class Win32_Service : Win32_BaseService
    {
      boolean  AcceptPause;
      boolean  AcceptStop;
      string   Caption;
      uint32   CheckPoint;
      string   CreationClassName;
      string   Description;
      boolean  DesktopInteract;
      string   DisplayName;
      string   ErrorControl;
      uint32   ExitCode;
      datetime InstallDate;
      string   Name;
      string   PathName;
      uint32   ProcessId;
      uint32   ServiceSpecificExitCode;
      string   ServiceType;
      boolean  Started;
      string   StartMode;
      string   StartName;
      string   State;
      string   Status;
      string   SystemCreationClassName;
      string   SystemName;
      uint32   TagId;
      uint32   WaitHint;
    };
```

And this is what you are asking:

```
        string   StartName;
```

I used PowerShell to get data about "Remote desktop" service on my laptop and i got a more data like this (some of that data are properties from Win32_BaseService, not Win32Service):

```
    DesktopInteract         : False
    DisconnectedSessions    : 1
    DisplayName             : Remote desktop services
    ErrorControl            : Normal
    ExitCode                : 1077
    InstallDate             :
    Name                    : TermService
    PathName                : C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k NetworkService
    ProcessId               : 0
    ServiceSpecificExitCode : 0
    ServiceType             : Share Process
    Started                 : False
    StartMode               : Manual
    StartName               : NT Authority\NetworkService
    State                   : Stopped
    Status                  : OK
    SystemCreationClassName : Win32_ComputerSystem
    SystemName              : NOTEBOOK
    TagId                   : 0
    TotalSessions           : 2
    WaitHint                : 0
```

I cant help with WMI in C#. Maybe you will find StartName property somewhere in class which you are using (i dont know what class it is because u didnt wrote).

Comment: That was enough to point me in the right direction and particularly to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141308/how-do-i-retrieve-the-username-that-a-windows-service-is-running-under)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to retrieve this information using WMI in C#:

```
public string GetWindowsServiceLoginCredentials(string serviceName)
    {
        var credentials = (
            from x 
                in new ManagementObjectSearcher($"SELECT StartName FROM Win32_Service WHERE Caption = '{serviceName}'")
                .Get()
                .Cast<ManagementObject>()
            select 
                x.GetPropertyValue("StartName")).FirstOrDefault();

        return credentials != null ? credentials.ToString() : "";
    }
```

You can use this to get other properties of the service, just change out the 'StartName' for the property you're interested in.

Comment: in new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", $"SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name = '{serviceName}'")