# Get List of Windows Services with Service Account

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I try to get a List of all Windows Services + the Service Account

For Example:

```
servicexyz.exe;Local Service
servicezyx.exe;ADUser123
```

I already tried ServiceController but I couldn't find a method or property to get the service account...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve the username that a Windows service is running under?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141308/how-do-i-retrieve-the-username-that-a-windows-service-is-running-under)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `System.Management` to get this info via native WMI - use the `Win32_Service` class as demonstrated in the 'possible dup' I cited above.

This technique can be used for a lot of system-level information that appears on the face of it not to be available in the .Net Framework.