# Username is not accessible on SessionLogoff and even sometime in SessionUnlock

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am writing a Windows Service(using C#, WCF) that is intended to record Windows user's session event and post it to some other WCF Service.

Below code sometimes works as expected but not always. It returns empty mostly in SessionUnlock, SessionLogoff events.

```
var usernmae = Machine.getInstance().getUsername();
```

The above code-line is used inside a utility function which is being called from  OnSessionChange event of Windows Service as below: -

```
protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
{
  var sessionDetails = sessionLogger.BuildSessionDetails(changeDescription);

  ....
}
```

and that BuildSessionDetails function is like: -

```
public class SessionLogger : ISessionLogger
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public SessionDetails BuildSessionDetails(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
        {
            SessionDetails sd = new SessionDetails();
            sd.ChangeTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
            sd.SessionId = changeDescription.SessionId.ToString();
            sd.ChangeType = changeDescription.Reason.ToString();

            //This is where I am EXTRACTING USERNAME
            sd.Username = Machine.getInstance().getUsername();
            ...
            ...
      }
   }
```

The expected result is username all time whenever the session event happens.

Any idea what is happening or causing here to not return the username always?

Comment: What is the Machine class?

Comment: It has the function of getting username same to  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47653931/2596347

Comment: And 
````C#
userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; 
````
is returning "SYSTEM"

Comment: Any suggestion/idea on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your code gets the UserName property from the Win32_ComputerSystem class. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystem) on that variable says:

> Name of a user that is logged on currently. This property must have a value. In a terminal services session, UserName returns the name of **the user that is logged on to the console** not the user logged on during the terminal service session.

Is that your intention?

You seem to consider this code to be a suitable alternative:

> userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

But that will always return the name of the user specified on your service's "Log On" tab — probably not what you want.

Exactly which "user" are you trying to get?

---

Edit based on comments:

To get the user name associated with the session that was changed:

1. In OnSessionChange(), get the sessionID value from the [SessionChangeDescription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.sessionchangedescription?view=netframework-4.8) parameter.
2. Use the sessionID in a call to the [WTSQuerySessionInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsquerysessioninformationa) function with the WTSUserName value to get the user name associated with the session.

That should work in all occasions except when a user has logged off (because the session will no longer be available to query). If that is an issue, you can work around that problem by:

1. Introducing a sessionID-to-username map in your application
2. Populating the map by enumerating all active sessions when your service starts
3. Adding to the map whenever you receive a logon event
4. Removing from the map (by sessionID) whenever there is a logoff event

Comment: Let me rephrase: - 
1. Users are in organization network using their own laptop/desktop
2. I need to record their local system sessions not their RDPs etc.  For example, how much times user was idle (session unlocked, session Logout etc.)
3. The suggested code-line returns "SYSTEM" instead of username. 

Hope you got my question.  So considering this, do you see any workaround or fixes?

Comment: And yes you are right, my requirement is not depend upon the Service's "Log On" tab based account. I am just keen to get the current username. Since, its user's individual machine, I assume there would be only 1 user at anytime and his/her system events like Lock, Unlock, Logon, Logout events, I am trying to send this information to centralized service.

Comment: For a workaround, I can store the username when service is started and then use that at each system event instead of querying every time; but here it is not guaranteed that I will get correct username at the very first time too.

Comment: Can anyone help me here?

Comment: First and foremost, thank you very much for such explanatory assistance. What if I build a cache when my service starts and use it at all session events? Will it work in logoff event as well?

Comment: Yes. You will get a logoff event (after the session has closed) and you will use the associated session ID to remove that entry from your cached list. Try it!

Comment: Ahh, it still gives "SYSTEM" as username when user logoff machine. :( Any other workaround?

Comment: You don't need the user name from the logoff event. That information will already be in the map your code maintains. Just look it up using the sessionID from the logoff event.

Comment: thanks for guidance. Can you please share some code snippet link? Even it fails to find username when system is shutdown and started again.

Comment: Please implement the 4 steps in the answer and post your code so that the community can review and provide guidance.